# Starting NDSolve from intermediate time step?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I always wondered if I could start `NDSolve` from an intermediate time step.

What I mean is, in the code sample below, if I were to run my solution from `tmin=0` to `tmax=2` and then I realize that my solution hasn't converged yet, could I just change my  `tmin` to `2` and then proceed with a larger `tmax` (in this case the solution coverges [attains steady state in this example] at `tmax=5`).

This is because very often I solve 4th order Nonlinear PDEs with `NDSolve`, some of which take over 70-80 minutes to complete (as I run them for long times of a million time steps or so) and then I realize that the solution hasn't converged yet. So can I just, as in my presumed working example, change my `tmin` to my `tmax` from the previous run and change my `tmax` to a larger run?

```
tmin = 0;
tmax = 5;
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
    u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, {t, tmin, tmax}, {x, 0, 5}];
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, tmin, tmax}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: By "converged" you mean "reached a steady state"? Regardless, you might use the old solution to give initial and boundary values for starting anew.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, steady state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could integrate up to some intermediate time, `tintermediate`, and then feed the result as initial conditions to the solver to propagate from `tintermediate` to `tmax`, like so:

```
tmin = 0;
tintermediate = 2;
tmax = 5;
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, 
    u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, 
   u, {t, tmin, tintermediate}, {x, 0, 5}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
    u[tintermediate, x] \[Equal] First@(u[tintermediate, x] /. sol), 
    u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, 
   u, {t, tintermediate, tmax}, {x, 0, 5}];
```

Comment: Thanks! Just so that I understand this right `sol2` is the solution from `t=2` to `t=5`...?

Comment: Yes, that is what it is

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I actually just learned the use of `@`!

Comment: ah yes. glad to be of help!

Answer (score 17):

As it turns out, the designers of `NDSolve[]` have precisely anticipated this sort of use; this is where you can use the [`` NDSolve`StateData `` framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html).

To use acl's example:

```
(* prepare PDE *)
state = First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
 u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, t, {x, 0, 5}]];


(* go up to t = 2 *)
NDSolve`Iterate[state, {0, 2}]
NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]

(* go up to t = 5 *)
NDSolve`Iterate[state, 5];
NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]
```

See the docs for more details.

Comment: good point, +1!

Comment: Awesome! I'll look into the documentation. This is quite nifty! (Not taking anything away from the previous answerer `:)`)

Comment: Why am I not able to plot the solution `u[t,x]` with `Plot3D[
 Evaluate[u[t, x]],
 {t, 2, 5},
 {x, 0, 5}
 ]` OR `Plot3D[
 u[t, x]/.sol,
 {t, 2, 5},
 {x, 0, 5}
 ]` where `sol=
NDSolve\`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]
`