# Plotting with NDSolve`StateData`

Tags: plotting, options, differential-equations

This question is a continuation of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5556).

As answered by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5558), I am able to iterate a solution.
However, I am unable to plot it.
I am sure that this has to do with my inability to understand how the plot routine works and I can't seem to figure it out:

```
state = First[
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
    u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, t, {x, 0, 5}]]

NDSolve`Iterate[state, 5]
NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]

Plot3D[
 Evaluate[u[t, x] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]],
 {t,0,2},
 {x, 0, 5}
 ]
```

gives me a blank plot with no curves. What am I doing wrong? I can't omit `{t, 0, 2}` as that would give me an error.

Comment: have a look at this: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html

Comment: @acl I did have a look at that. When I replaced the u[t,x,y] equation with u[t,x], all I got was blank plots.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the interpolation object that's returned, it's not a function u(t,x) only u(x) with fixed t. In fact, it returns both u[x] and u'[x] for fixed t. So try

```
state = First[
NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0}, u, t, {x, 0, 5}]]

Table[NDSolve`Iterate[state, t];
Plot[NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"][[All, 2]], {x, 0, 5},
PlotRange -> 1], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for making the distinction between `u[t,x]` and `u[x]`. It wasn't obvious to me! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
L = -10;
state = First[
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{D[u[t, x], 
       t] == + D[u[t, x], x, x] - Sin[u[t, x]],
     u[0, x] == Exp[-(x^2)],
     u[t, -L] == u[t, L]}, u, t, {x, -L, L}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[
   NDSolve`Iterate[state, tau ];

   Plot[Evaluate[
     u[tau, x] /. 
      NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state, "Forward"]], {x, -L, L}, 
    PlotRange -> {-1/4, 1/4}],
   {tau, 0., 3., .5}], 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You know, I'll have to check my `[` and see if all is well with my code.